# Can not install geoserver 2.5.1 on Mac OSX 10.9.3

Tags: geoserver, installation, osx

I am trying to install geoserver 2.5.1 on my Mac (OSX 10.9.3) but i am getting the error “GeoServer.app” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Trash.

Can you pls help?

Comment: How did you try to install? The "Mac OS X Binary" option seems to be preferred on the manual page http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/installation/osx/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable a security setting before you install Geoserver at Mac OSX:

On Mac OSX:

- Open *System Preferences*
- Go to *Security & Privacy*
- Select the *General* tab
- Enable *Anywhere* under *Allow Application Downloads from:*
  (open the lock before)

-> After that you can install/open Geoserver

(Testet with Geoserver 2.5.1 / OSX 10.9.3)